# system.teminate() is not invoking all phases of CoordinatedShutdown in akka

Tags: akka, actor

my work required some advanced cleanup during application termination, so I added a task in CoordinatedShutdown's before-service-unbind phase.

The task is **being executed** when the application receives SIGTERM from outside but not invoked when system.terminate is called within the application.

Akka doc says it should be executed when actor system terminates, do anyone have any insight that why it is not getting invoked during terminate?